# VM provisioning fails on Azure Java SDK - beta 5

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk

I am trying to create a Virtual Machine using the Azure Java SDK. I am working with the new beta 5 release, I have a working solution on beta 4. I started testing beta 5 and have not been able to provision a VM thus far.

Even a simple create as shown below fails.

```
azure.virtualMachines().define("myLinuxVM")
                .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
                .withNewResourceGroup("azure-beta5-group")
                .withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
                .withPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()
                .withNewPrimaryPublicIpAddress("mylinuxvmdns")
                .withPopularLinuxImage(KnownLinuxVirtualMachineImage.UBUNTU_SERVER_16_04_LTS)
                .withRootUsername("tirekicker")
                .withRootPassword("mypassword")
                .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_A0)
                .create();
```

I am using Maven to resolve dependencies with artifact

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta5</version>
        </dependency>
```

The create fails with the exception.

```
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.createExceptionFromResponse(AzureClient.java:591)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.access$000(AzureClient.java:34)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$1.call(AzureClient.java:135)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$1.call(AzureClient.java:132)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with beta-6-SNAPSHOT?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Nope, will do that.